# Which items are affected by an area Shatter spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

When cast to affect a 5-ft. radius spread (its first mode), the [*shatter*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/shatter.html#shatter) spell (CRB 341) has the following effect:

> Used as an area attack, shatter destroys **nonmagical objects** of crystal, glass, ceramic, or porcelain. All such **unattended** objects within a 5-foot radius of the point of origin are smashed into dozens of pieces by the spell. Objects weighing more than 1 pound per your level are not affected, but all other objects of the appropriate composition are shattered.

However, the saving throw it allows for its first mode, "Will negates (object)", has the (object) tag, which carries the following implications (CRB 216):

> The spell can be cast on objects, which receive saving throws only if they are **magical** or if they are **attended** (held, worn, grasped, or the like) by a creature resisting the spell, in which case the object uses the creature’s saving throw bonus unless its own bonus is greater.

No exception is made in the spell description, that I can see. Barring the odd case of an attended or magical item's success or failure on a Will save carrying weight, is the saving throw line simply redundant?

Answer (score 5):

The spell description states that it only affects non-magical objects. Then it says that all **unattended** (non-magical) objects are smashed. So if there is any **attended** non-magical object fitting the before-going description (crystaline, etc.), they get a save. What kind of save? A will save.

Comment: This is my understanding of it, but your answer doesn't lay it out cleanly enough for anyone looking for a ruling in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

The caster, when he casts the spell [*shatter*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) in its first mode, designates a [point of origin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) for the spell within the spell's range. Within the spell's area, each object that is *both* unattended (i.e. not carried, held, possessed wielded, or worn by a creature) *and* appropriate (i.e. nonmagical and made from "crystal, glass, ceramic, or porcelain") is destroyed, and each object that is *both* appropriate *and* attended makes a Will saving throw using the saving throw modifier of the creature attending the object; failure means that object's destroyed. Everything else is unaffected.

This does, however, make the *shatter* spell's saving throw entry for its first mode a little wonky.

### The *(object)* portion of [*shatter*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/shatter.html#shatter)'s first saving throw entry is unusual

When the [*shatter*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/shatter.html#shatter) spell's used as an area spell, it probably would've been enough for spell's designer to've listed the saving throw as *Will negates* then let the spell description do the heavy lifting of detailing what *that* means rather than asking the reader to pointlessly look up the details of the rarely-used *(object)* tag, which, in this case, brings little to table. That is, when used as an area spell the spell *shatter* isn't cast *on* the objects but on the area itself, so the saving throw here entry of *Will negates (object)* is pretty much the same as *Will negates*.

*Except* that a saving throw entry of *Will negates* implies that the creature makes *just one* lone Will saving throw against the *entire* effect of the spell *shatter*, with success leaving unharmed *all* the creature's appropriate stuff and failure rendering broken *all* of the creature's appropriate stuff. To clarify that *isn't* the case and that the creature makes saving throws for its attended appropriate mundane objects individually, the author would've then had to've said as much in the spell's description. Thus, here, the *(object)* tag becomes more *reminder* ("Make a separate Will saving throw for each appropriate object in your possession!") than *rules* ("Do the impossible and make several objects—rather than the *area*—the subject of an area spell!").

I agree that it would've been great had *Pathfinder* seized the opportunity to revise some of the game's classic elements—like the spell [*shatter*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/shatter.html#shatter)—so that they were absolutely (*ahem*) crystal clear, but the game contented itself with functional—if imperfect—legacy spells dating back to the turn of the century that had been working fine as printed for [over a decade](http://www.opengamingfoundation.org/srd.html),—in this case, not fixing what isn't outright broken.